# Is there a good comprehension way to access several 2D arrays burried in dicts

Tags: python

So for legacy reasons I have to deal with a data store that has the format

```
obj.dict1 = {keyA:{key1:(3xN np array),
                   key2:(3xN np array),
                   key3:(3xN np array)}
             keyB:{key1:(3xN np array),
                   key2:(3xN np array),
                   key3:(3xN np array)}
            }
```

and I am trying to get two different lists quickly:

1. `[ obj.dict1[keyA][key1](0,:), obj.dict1[keyA][key2](0,:), obj.dict1[keyA][key3](0,:) ]`
2. `[ obj.dict1[keyA][key1](0,:), obj.dict1[keyB][key1](0,:) ]`

So far for both of these I am building a for loop that goes over either the inner or out keys. It works alright but was hoping for something more pythonic with list comprehension

**EDIT**

The loop for 1. is

```
keyList = ['key1','key2','key3']
tmpArray = np.zeros((3,N))
for ii in range(3):
    tmpArray[ii,:] = obj.dict1['keyA'][keyList[ii]][0,:]
```

If it can't be faster or simpler that's fine but this is then inside another for loop that gets repeated quite a few (>50) times.

Comment: A list comprehension might not be an improvement, especially if it would be long/complex. Can you share the current loop?

Comment: you missed a `:` after `for loop`

Comment: Yeah, I copied it wrong but that isn't the issue I'm having in the real code

Comment: are you writing `(0,:)` to slice the numpy array?

Comment: Yep. I need to pull out only a single row of the arrays for any given list but in other places it may be (1,:) or (2,:). All get used eventually

Comment: shouldn't you use `[]` instead of `()`

Comment: Yep. It's just late and I'm not focused on the syntax here really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this list comprehension `[dict1[key][key2][0,:] for key in dict1 for key2 in dict1[key]]` and it ran pretty quickly... in fact, `time taken 0.0019943714141845703` seconds for N = 100000

```py
import numpy as np

N = 100000
dict1 ={
    "keyA":{
             "key1": np.random.rand(3,N),
             "key2": np.random.rand(3,N),
             "key3": np.random.rand(3,N)
            },

     "keyB":{
             "key1": np.random.rand(3,N),
             "key2": np.random.rand(3,N),
             "key3": np.random.rand(3,N)
            }
}

temp = []
for key in dict1:
    for key2 in dict1[key]:
        temp.append(dict1[key][key2][0:1])
        
start = time.time()
print([dict1[key][key2][0,:] for key in dict1 for key2 in dict1[key]])
stop = time.time()   
print("time taken",stop-start)
```

Comment: I'm feeling good about where my python is at but didn't know you could stack the comprehensions like that. Also just used your code to do 10,000 loops of each and the timing difference is small and fluctuates between which is faster. Thanks for your help